# Reverse a node by recursion

Tags: python-3.x

I have a node that I need to reverse by recursion in Python. I used the following code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
       '''
       Initiate a node
       :param value: float | int | str
       '''
       self.value = value
       self.nxt = None

def reverse(n):
    """
    Reverse a given linked-node
    :param n: Node
    :return: None
    """
    if n is None or n.nxt is None:
        return 
    else:
        rest = n.nxt
        n.nxt = None
        reverse(rest)
        #reach the end of rest
        current = rest             
        while current.nxt:
            current = current.nxt
        current.nxt = n
        n = rest
```

This does not work of course because changing the value of n just change it's reference not the actual node, so the result I get is only the same node with its next = None! 
Any help?!

Answer (score 0):

I made some adjustment and it works:

```
def reverse(n, prev=None):
    """ Reverse a given linked-node
        :param n: Node
        :return: None"""
    if n is None or n.nxt is None:
        return n

    rest = n.nxt
    n.nxt = prev
    return reverse(rest, n)
```

Comment: You cant use prev nor edit the constructor of the class nor add an argument. It was a question on the exam. Not to mention you need here to mutate not to return a new node. 
But thank you for trying to help.